# Rails fetch by a many to many field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have two classes

Post And Tag

```
class Post 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

class Tag
    has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
```

I want to be able to search for posts by tag but what I have doesn't work

```
@posts = Post.joins(:tags).where("tags.id", @tag.id)
```

But whats happening is its returning all the posts regardless. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@posts = @tag.posts
```

This will give you posts for a particular tag

Comment: this worked! but it led me to find the bug in my original code. `    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags` in the tag class

Answer (score 1):

This the correct syntax for what you're trying to do there.

*I'm not sure it will return what you're expecting though*.

```
Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: @tag.id })
```